# Pandas - conversion to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this small issue, where I first concatenate 3 columns in a DataFrame ['Year', 'Month', 'Day'] into a single column called ['Date'], and then I apply to this column datetime conversion, but afterwards when I check this column with .info() method, it still contains objects, not datetime objects:
[image: Failed Datetime conversion]

DataFrame I am operating on is the first item in 'output' list, hence the address I apply before .info() method.

Any ideas why it does not obey me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign it back to dataframe['Date']. [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime) is not an inplace operation it returns back the Series with dtype datetime64.

```
dataframe['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Doh, simple problems are the hardest to come up with fixes to :) Thanks mate, it was too obvious for me to notice. I wonder why .to_datetime() method does not support 'inplace = True' argument in the first place, to avoid confusions like this one...